# How to remove Reflected Cross-site Scripting in the website url name

Tags: security, xss, csrf, owasp

I have my website in which when i type  *http://someurl/login.aspx/'==alert(1)=='* 
 causes the website to open a dialog box leading to a reflected XSS.

When i tried other websites such as google or facebook ,both of them leads to a page 404 page not found.

How to create that kind of functionality in my website to avoid any future security issues related to XSS.

Answer (score 1):

encode your request parameters to javascript encoded form. There are many libraries also available in the market to encode your parameters.
Also, make sure the JavaScriptEncode method must be used over the HTML binding shortcut (<%#:) because the shortcut only works for HTML contexts.

Comment: Can u provide an example.It will be helpful as i am new in this field.thanks

Comment: I have shared one basic example in below comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code handling the query params (`==alert(1)==`). You probably take the user input without sanitization and print it back on the browser, in a JS context. See [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) for more details.

Comment: i am simply typing in the url  http://someurl/login.aspx/'==alert(1)=='  instead of http://someurl/login.aspx. Earlier one is giving me alert box saying 1. I want it to show an error page.My application is in .net

Comment: Please share your code, it will be hard to advice how to fix without it. In general, as suggested above - use sanitization (see this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting)) should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic example for url encoding in javascript

```
var uri = 'https://mozilla.org/?x=шеллы';
var encoded = encodeURI(uri);
console.log(encoded);
// expected output: "https://mozilla.org/?x=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B"

try {
  console.log(decodeURI(encoded));
  // expected output: "https://mozilla.org/?x=шеллы""
} catch(e) { // catches a malformed URI
  console.error(e);
```

}